# How to call a function within an instance? Python & Kivy

Tags: python, class, kivy, instances

Good Afternoon all thanks for any insight....again!

How do I call the `def clearwidgets` from `def changetxt` within an instance, if I use `self.parent.clearwidgets`, I receive anchor layout does not support this, which would be correct, as the ultimate parent instance is named `root` or `GameApp`? 
Which is the parent above the parent. If that make sense.

What I'm trying to achieve is like a screen manager/controller to swap from one layout to another: start menu, main play area, end game, credits etc.

I’ve looked at Kivy source code on Github for the demo game but they just go straight to the play area with no splash screen etc.

I even tried adding `root=anchorlayout` just under the imports and using global `root` in the `changetxt()` but receive the error global none not found.

Again Thanks and Appreciated

```
import kivy


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder




class launchScreenMenu(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(launchScreenMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        menuanchor = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left',anchor_y='bottom')
        menu = StackLayout(orientation='bt-lr',size_hint=(0.5,1))
        about_btn = Button(text='About',size_hint=(0.3,0.1))
        help_btn = Button(text='Settings',size_hint=(0.3,0.1))
        settings_btn = Button(text='Help',size_hint=(0.3,0.1))

        menu.add_widget(about_btn)
        menu.add_widget(help_btn)
        menu.add_widget(settings_btn)
        menuanchor.add_widget(menu)
        return self.add_widget(menuanchor)

class launchScreenBtn(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(launchScreenBtn, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        play_btn = Button(text="Play")
        self.anchor_x = 'center'
        self.anchor_y = 'center'
        self.size_hint = 0.2,0.2
        self.add_widget(play_btn)
        play_btn.bind(on_press=self.changetxt)


    def changetxt(self,play_btn):
        play_btn.text = 'Game Over'
        clearwidgets()

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = AnchorLayout()
        root.add_widget(launchScreenMenu())
        root.add_widget(launchScreenBtn())

        return root

    def clearwidgets(self):
        root.clear_widgets()



if __name__=='__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An essential idea of object-oriented programming (and of programming in general) is that you need to keep references to objects you want to do things with.

For example, in your `GameApp.build` method, you're creating an `AnchorLayout` object, assign it to the `root` local variable, and then add widgets to it through that local variable.

Your question seems to be, "how do I keep issuing commands to that object *after* the `build` method has finished running?" I'm noticing an attempt to call `root.clear_widgets()` in the `clearWidgets` method, which of course doesn't work because `root` is a *local* variable -- it has no existence outside of the method it's used in.

This is where object attributes come in. See, an object is a chunk of state that you can pass around in your program. You can add more state to any object you create. For example, in your `launchScreenBtn` class's  `__init__` method, you're setting the `anchor_x`, `anchor_y` and `size_hint` attributes of the instance being created. As long as you have a reference to a `launchScreenBtn` instance, you can access those attributes (with e.g. `my_lsbtn.anchor_x`), regardless of whether you're in a function/method.

So what you want to do is make use of that mechanism more. In your `GameApp.build` method, you don't want to make `root` a local variable: you want to make it an attribute instead (`self.root = AnchorLayout()`). That way, in your `clearwidgets` method, you can access it, calling `self.root.clear_widgets()`.

Apply similar principles through the rest of your application: whenever you have something you'd like to keep manipulating *after* you've exited the method it's defined in, it's a sign you want to make it an attribute.

While you're at it, you should read a few tutorials on object-oriented programming, because it looks like your grasp of it is shaky. Start with the Python tutorial's section on classes: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks for that :) , will give it a bash, I totally agree with you, I really struggle to understand oop and classes, I think another topic added the same reference today, so will read up on that tonight. Again thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thanks, I found that a mixture of your explanation and Ryan G's example, along with adding app = App.get_running_app()
        app.clearwidgets() in the  changetxt function got it working, but I will go back to basics to I can try and refactor the code. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

When you add widgets for and launchScreenBtn() can you modify the class to accept the GameApp instance of self?

```
class launchScreenBtn(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, mainApp,**kwargs):
        super(launchScreenBtn, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mainApp = mainApp # Local variable to reference parent
        self.play_btn = Button(text="Play")
        self.anchor_x = 'center'
        self.anchor_y = 'center'
        self.size_hint = 0.2,0.2
        self.add_widget(play_btn)
        self.play_btn.bind(on_press=self.changetxt)


    def changetxt(self,play_btn):
        self.play_btn.text = 'Game Over'
        self.mainApp.clearwidgets()

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = AnchorLayout()
        self.root.add_widget(launchScreenMenu())
        self.root.add_widget(launchScreenBtn(self)) # Add GameApp reference self to Btn Class

        return self.root

    def clearwidgets(self):
        self.root.clear_widgets()
```

This is usually how I would handle something like this in wxPython, and I believe it should work here as well.

Comment: You'll need to have `root` as an attribute not just a local varirable, as @Max Noel points out, too.

Comment: correct. After relooking the code over again, themethods need some work, as clearwidgets will have no idea what root is unless it is instantiated in the build method as self.root and referenced in clear widgets as self.root as well. "when in doubt, add self."

Comment: hey as the comment above :), this seems to work app = App.get_running_app()
        app.clearwidgets(), along with a mixture of your code and max noels explanation